# How to install nvidia driver without the graphics card installed on debian 9.1.0

Tags: nvidia

I have the debian 9.1.0 lxde amd64 version. I want to install the driver for the card gtx 750ti, but I just can't because if I use the card in debian, the monitor doesn't show anything after select the "Debian" grub entry (keeps black), but if I use the onboard graphics I can use the system.

I plan use a cuda application, and heavy math processing.

Edit: now the monitor says: "Mode not suported". The refresh rate is above the supported (how do I write this?)

Edit2: I'm using debian with lxde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

Luckily, the terminal mode works with the graphics card. I used the `.run` file from nvidia to install the driver

1. At the login screen (**can be black screen**) hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 (to open the terminal), then type `nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and add `contrib non-free` at the end of each line (after each `main`)
2. `apt update && apt upgrade`
3. `apt install firmware-linux build-essential gcc-multilib`
4. `apt build-dep linux`
5. `systemctl stop lightdm`
6. `cd /home/user/Downloads` (replease `user` with your user name)
7. `chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux*.run` (replease the `*` with the rest of the name of your file)
8. `./NVIDIA-Linux*.run` (replease the `*` with the rest of the name of your file)

During the instalation you'll be asked to replease current xorg configuration files. Say `yes` and restart your computer after logout from your user. At the login screen you open the terminal again and type:

9. `sudo systemctl stop lightdm`
10. `cd /home/user/Downloads` (replease `user` with your user name)
11. `chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux*.run` (replease the `*` with the rest of the name of your file)
12. `./NVIDIA-Linux*.run` (replease the `*` with the rest of the name of your file)

It answers the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it works that way. Anyway Nvidia on Debian stretch crashes it. I reinstalled my Debian distro two times due to Nvidia graphics drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a stupid question, but have you changed the port on which your screen is connected?

I guess that your onboard graphics' output is on the motherboard and the gtx's output is... on the gtx.

If it doesn't solve your problem, try to run `lspci -nn | grep nvidia`. It will tell you if your graphics card is detected by the system.

Then, just go on with [this tutorial from debian's wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers).

Comment: I can't use the system, but I have windows installed too. Can I edit some system file through windows?

Comment: I can use only one port of my graphics card, which is dvi-i with a vga-dvi-i adapter